# How to find a pattern that does not contains a subpattern?

Tags: regex, netbeans

I'm working on a Netbeans project (Java), and I'm checking if everything is allright. I've just discovered that the Find tool in Netbeans supports regular expressions, so I used the following Regex to find the *correct* code:

```
ps\.set.*\(3, c0.get\((.*)\)\);(\n.*){3}.*ps\.set.*\(7, c1.get\(t\).get\(\1\)\);\n.*ps\.addBatch\(\);
                       ^^                                                ^^
                       Subpattern 1...              ...must also appear here
```

Example (matched by Regex above):

```java
ps.setString(3, c0.get(fooPattern));      // "fooPattern" here...
ps.setDouble(5, s.get(k));
ps.setDouble(6, 0d);
ps.setLong(7, c1.get(t).get(fooPattern)); // ... must also be here
ps.addBatch();
```

What I need it to check if the subpattern `1` appears in the second position. This Regex works. However, I need to find all occurrences where this *does not happen*.

Example (what I'd like to find):

```java
ps.setString(3, c0.get(fooPattern));      // "fooPattern" here...
ps.setDouble(5, s.get(k));
ps.setDouble(6, 0d);
ps.setLong(7, c1.get(t).get(barPattern)); // ... is NOT here
ps.addBatch();
```

So, the specific question is: **How to modify this Regex to find all occurrences where Subpattern `1` is not repeated in the position it should be?**

Comment: Are you aware that `(\n.*){3}`  stores only the third line in the end? To negate it, use `(?!\1)\n.*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I'm aware... That's not the pattern I need to match, but the first one (which is what follows after the third line feed).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, I messed up the markers... what I need to match is the `(.*)` part marked, not the line feed. Just corrected the post

Comment: The only way I could think of is to use a negative lookahead or lookbehind assertion. Find the larger string and the cases where it doesn't match your other string. Something like adding `(?<!\1.*?\1)` to confirm that there are not 2 instances of your backreference. I can't test at the moment, but that might get you what you need.

Comment: @JonUpchurch Unfortunately, it does not work. It pops out this error message: `Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead as I have already mentioned, just use a consuming subpattern instead of the `\1` (that was consuming text in your original regex). Also, do not forget that to match a literal dot, you need to escape it.

```
ps\.set.*\(3, c0\.get\((.*)\)\);(\n.*){3}.*ps\.set.*\(7, c1\.get\(t\)\.get\((?!\1\))[^()]*\)\);\n.*ps\.addBatch\(\);
                                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bA3rD6/2)

The `(?!\1\))` negative lookahead restricts the more generic `[^()]*` pattern (that matches zero or more characters other than `(` and `)`, you may replace it with `.*` if there can be parentheses inside) making it fail if these 0+ chars are equal to the value captured into Group 1.